# How to make a general type that can be xml, json or html

Tags: c#, json, xml, oop

I have a program that at some point will load a text file. This text file's content will either be in xml, json or html format.

My current approach looks like this:

1. Load the file, parse it, check if it's json,
   Yes: save it to a predefined string,
   No:
2. Load the file, parse it, check if it's xml,
   Yes: save it to a predefined XmlDocument,
   No:
3. Load the file, parse it, check if it's html,
   Yes: save it to a predefined HtmlDocument,
   No: Error

And in the end I need to distinguish. Check all of them. And whichever is not null will be further processed.

Also I had to instantiate the XmlDocument and the HtmlDocument like this:

```
XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDoc = null;,
```

to make sure they're actually null when distinguishing in the end. Because if I only construct, they won't be null.

This looks very dirty. I know I can do something with interfaces and maybe a factory. But what confuses me is: Say I build an Interface IDocument, doesn't the content of this thing have to be generic? I mean I have different file types.. I'm very confused.

Comment: It depends on the processing that is performed on each of these different inputs. Is your processing of json different to xml? Maybe the processing code should be lumped with the check type and parse steps, then your interface would expose the processed files, not the raw file

Comment: Just a thought on your content. All the content of the files are just string, unless its binary serialized. So get out the content of the file, try to parse it as the different types. that way, you only load the file once, but tryparse multiple times :)

Comment: Yes it is different. I’m performing the same action on them (updating a value depending on a xpath/jsonpath. The logic is pretty much the same but oviobviously the way I manipulate each is different.

Comment: I'm wondering if do you have an option to alter your program to accept .xml , .json, .html file instead of just .text file? That might be easier to handle than allowing to load a txt file that contains those different format.

Comment: Can you use MIME type to determine which type of file is being loaded? If so, I would create a factory that uses MIME type to pick the appropriate class to load and manipulate the data. So, 4 classes. 1 for parsing/manipulating each type of file + 1 factory.

Comment: Come to think of it, even if you cannot use MIME type, you can always have a class who's job it is to determine the file type, then use that information to pass the string to the appropriate class for manipulating that type of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should still check for these 3 types, but however you can create your own class and implement these checking and parsing inside your own class (or interface):

You can create an implicit casting for all three types so that you can set its value with any of these 3 types:

```
public class MultiDoc
{
     private XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
     private string type = "";
     public void Load(string content)
     {
          //do your checking to match the types here
     }

     public T Get<T>()
     {
          if(typeof(T) == typeof(XmlDocument))
              return xml;
          elseif ...
     }

     //implicit casting type XmlDocument
     public MultiDoc(XmlDocument input) {  xml = input; type = "xml"; }
     public static implicit operator MultiDoc(XmlDocument input) { return new MultiDoc(input); }

    //do same casting for other types.

}
```

Now Becuase of implicit casting you can simply do:

```
XmlDocument somexml = ....
MultiDoc mc = somexml;  //implicity cast XmlDocument to MultiDoc
```

And for getting:

```
XmlDocument somexml = mc.Get<XmlDocument>();
```